# How can i set another data into constructor DataModel in Retrofit in Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

In my application I should load data from server and for this job I use **`Retrofit`** library.
In my application i want load **string** data **from server** and i should load **images** from **drawable folder** .
I can load string from server and show it on `textview`, but when add images i don't know how can i it?!
**DataModel:**

```
public class Retrofit_ColoniesModel {

    //Load from server
    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("slug")
    private String slug;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("parent")
    private Integer parent;
    @SerializedName("post_count")
    private Integer post_count;

    //Load from local
    private int[] image;

    public Retrofit_ColoniesModel(Integer id, String slug, String title, String description, Integer parent, Integer post_count,
                                  int[] image) {
        this.id = id;
        this.slug = slug;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.post_count = post_count;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSlug() {
        return slug;
    }

    public void setSlug(String slug) {
        this.slug = slug;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Integer parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Integer getPost_count() {
        return post_count;
    }

    public void setPost_count(Integer post_count) {
        this.post_count = post_count;
    }

    public int[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int[] image) {
        this.image= image;
    }
```

**DataModelResponse:**

```
public class Retrofit_ColoniesModelResponse {

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("count")
    private int count;
    @SerializedName("categories")
    private List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> categories;


    public List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

**Retrofit code in activity:**

```
// Retrofit //////////
Retrofit_ApiInterface apiInterface = Retrofit_ApiClient.getClient().create(Retrofit_ApiInterface.class);
Call<Retrofit_ColoniesModelResponse> call = apiInterface.getResponse();

call.enqueue(new Callback<Retrofit_ColoniesModelResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Retrofit_ColoniesModelResponse> call, Response<Retrofit_ColoniesModelResponse> response) {
        List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> models = response.body().getCategories();

        mAdaper = new ColoniesAdapter(context, models);
        colonies_RecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaper);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Retrofit_ColoniesModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
//////////////////////
```

I want save images into Array, such as :

```
                    final int[] colImages = {
                            R.drawable.colonies_image_food,
                            R.drawable.colonies_image_medical,
                            R.drawable.colonies_image_tecgnolegy,
                            R.drawable.colonies_image_entertenement,
                            R.drawable.colonies_image_car,
                            R.drawable.colonies_image_model,
                            R.drawable.colonies_image_sport,
                    };
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class ColoniesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ColoniesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> mDateSet;
    private Context mContext;
    private SparseBooleanArray expandState = new SparseBooleanArray();

    public ColoniesAdapter(Context context, List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> dataSet) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mDateSet = dataSet;
        for (int i = 0; i < mDateSet.size(); i++) {
            expandState.append(i, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.colonies_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.colonies_title.setText(mDateSet.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.colonies_title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = holder.getPosition();
                Retrofit_ColoniesModel model = mDateSet.get(pos);
                v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), Category_page.class)
                        .putExtra("categoryTitle", model.getTitle())
                        .putExtra("categoryID", model.getId()));
            }
        });

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(mDateSet.get(position).getImage()[position])
                .placeholder(R.drawable.post_image)
                .crossFade()
                .override(700, 400)
                .into(holder.colonies_image);

        holder.colonies_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int pos = holder.getPosition();
                Retrofit_ColoniesModel model = mDateSet.get(pos);
                v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), Category_page.class)
                        .putExtra("categoryTitle", model.getTitle())
                        .putExtra("categoryID", model.getId()));
            }
        });

        holder.colonies_description.setText(mDateSet.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.colonies_count.setText("مطالب موجود در کلونی : " + mDateSet.get(position).getPost_count());

        holder.expandableLayout.setInterpolator(mDateSet.get(position).getInterpolator());
        holder.expandableLayout.setExpanded(expandState.get(position));
        holder.expandableLayout.setListener(new ExpandableLayoutListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onPreOpen() {
                createRotateAnimator(holder.buttonLayout, 0f, 180f).start();
                expandState.put(position, true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPreClose() {
                createRotateAnimator(holder.buttonLayout, 180f, 0f).start();
                expandState.put(position, false);
            }
        });
        holder.buttonLayout.setRotation(expandState.get(position) ? 180f : 0f);
        holder.buttonLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                onClickButton(holder.expandableLayout);
            }
        });
    }

    private void onClickButton(final ExpandableLayout expandableLayout) {
        expandableLayout.toggle();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDateSet.size();
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        mDateSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mDateSet.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void add(List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> models) {
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void update(List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> models) {
        mDateSet.clear();
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView colonies_title, colonies_description, colonies_count;
        private ImageView colonies_image;
        private ExpandableLinearLayout expandableLayout;
        private RelativeLayout buttonLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            colonies_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colonies_colony_title_text);
            colonies_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colonies_cover_image);

            colonies_description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colonies_expandable_description_text);
            colonies_count = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colonies_count_title_text);

            buttonLayout = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colonies_expandable_button);
            expandableLayout = (ExpandableLinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.colonies_expandable_layout);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


/*                    v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), PostShow_page.class)
                            .putExtra("title", model.getTitle())
                            .putExtra("image", model.getThumbnail()));*/
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public ObjectAnimator createRotateAnimator(final View target, final float from, final float to) {
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "rotation", from, to);
        animator.setDuration(300);
        animator.setInterpolator(Utils.createInterpolator(Utils.LINEAR_INTERPOLATOR));
        return animator;
    }
}
```

I don't know how can i add int[] into my constructor, because in retrofit fill the constructor with `List<Retrofit_ColoniesModel> models = response.body().getCategories();` .

How can i fix my issue? I really need this tutorial, please help me. Thanks all <3

Comment: do you want to access inner class variables ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array of images is static (don't depend on the server) then you could just do the following:

```
public class Retrofit_ColoniesModel {
...
private static final int[] colImages = {
                        R.drawable.colonies_image_food,
                        R.drawable.colonies_image_medical,
                        R.drawable.colonies_image_tecgnolegy,
                        R.drawable.colonies_image_entertenement,
                        R.drawable.colonies_image_car,
                        R.drawable.colonies_image_model,
                        R.drawable.colonies_image_sport,
                };
```

But if this array is not static (depends on the server response) then I suggest you to map to an array of Strings that describe each image, and the server should respond with those Strings, for example:

```
"images":["IMAGE1", "IMAGE2"]
```

And then have a helper class that could map between those string keys to the actual R.drawable resources.

Let me know if you need sample code.

Comment: Your help is good, but when change my codes, show me Force Close error! can you send me your email? please

Comment: When clean project, Froce Close error is fix automatically :D . thanks for your help my dear friend <3

Answer (score 0):

**Non-static Nested Classes (Inner Classes)**

Non-static nested classes in Java are also called inner classes. Inner classes are associated with an instance of the enclosing class. Thus, you must first create an instance of the enclosing class to create an instance of an inner class. Here is an example inner class definition:

```
public class Outer {

  public class Inner {
  }

}
```

Here is how you create an instance of the Inner class:

```
Outer outer = new Outer();
Outer.Inner inner = outer.new Inner();
```

Notice how you put new after the reference to the outer class in order to create an instance of the inner class.

Non-static nested classes (inner classes) have access to the fields of the enclosing class, even if they are declared private. Here is an example of that: